# How to programatically disable contacts editing in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

In Outlook we would need to disable editing of the contacts which were imported from external source (as part of our add-in). To distinguish such contacts we've introduced user-defined property, which we are setting during the import (e.g. ExternalId).

But how can you in the code disable editing functionality for such contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can disable it!

You can either disable showing the dialog with the contact details (key hint: hook to `Application.ItemLoad`, there you can cancel the event in case it is a contact you don't want to edit)

Or, preferrably, you can refuse saving of the changes. See sample code.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += Inspectors_NewInspector;
}

private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
    Outlook.ContactItem contact = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.ContactItem;
    if (null != contact)
    {
        if (Utils.IsNonEditableContact(contact))
        {
            contact.Write += CancelSaveEventForContact;
        }
    }
}        

private void CancelSaveEventForCrmContact(ref bool Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Editing of the this contacts in Outlook is not allowed.", "I'm sorry!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no trivial way to disable editing contacts in Outlook.

But! You can develop a custom UI which can prevent contacts from editing in most cases - replace the default UI in Inspectors and Explorers. So, users will get your custom UI where you can allow edit contacts or not. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.

You may also find [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) helpful.